# How can I align the text numbers?

Tags: html, css

How can I get this text to align correctly? I would like the 9 over the 9 in 19.

[image]

This is the code block to loop through and print the numbers.

```
for(i=1; i<37; i++)
{
    var inTrack = IsInArray(i, state.track);
    var lessThan10 = i<10;
    var newLine = i%10 == 0;

    if(inTrack && lessThan10) show += "<span id='tracked'>&nbsp;&nbsp;"+i+"</span>";
    if(inTrack && !lessThan10) show += "<span id='tracked'>&nbsp;"+i+"</span>";
    if(!inTrack && lessThan10) show += "<span id='untracked'>&nbsp;&nbsp;"+i+"</span>";
    if(!inTrack && !lessThan10) show += "<span id='untracked'>&nbsp;"+i+"</span>";
    if(newLine) show += "<br/>";
    show +="\t";
}
```

This is the style for the tracked and untracked numbers.

```
#untracked {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #0f0101;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
}

#tracked {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #4802b9;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
}
```

Comment: Try using `table`

Answer (score 1):

You’re doing it right. Just use a mono spaced font.

Comment: I like your solution the best because it solved my problem quickly. I don't know if I should check it though because computer science people might not think that is the actual proper solution. Hopefully the community can vote.

Comment: If you had anything besides digits in there, I would recommend justified text in table cells. But numbers look just fine in monospace. There are even proportionally spaced fonts that have monospaced digits in them.

Answer (score 0):

Use inline-block and text align

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}

div {
 width: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
  <span>9</span>
  <span>10</span>
  <span>11</span>
  <span>12</span>
  <span>13</span>
  <span>14</span>
  <span>15</span>
  <span>16</span>
  <span>17</span>
  <span>18</span>
  <span>19</span>
  <span>20</span>
  <span>21</span>
  <span>22</span>
  <span>23</span>
  <span>24</span>
  <span>25</span>
  <span>26</span>
  <span>27</span>
  <span>28</span>
  <span>29</span>
</div>
```

CSS Grid

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
  <span>9</span>
  <span>10</span>
  <span>11</span>
  <span>12</span>
  <span>13</span>
  <span>14</span>
  <span>15</span>
  <span>16</span>
  <span>17</span>
  <span>18</span>
  <span>19</span>
  <span>20</span>
  <span>21</span>
  <span>22</span>
  <span>23</span>
  <span>24</span>
  <span>25</span>
  <span>26</span>
  <span>27</span>
  <span>28</span>
  <span>29</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `min-width` may fail to consistently format things correctly if some numbers are big and others are small

Answer (score 0):

If you're using variable width fonts, you can't do so without using some kind of formatting. Given that you're rendering HTML, that means using markup. Alternately, you can use a monospace font in a `<pre>` tag and pad each number that is shorter than the longest number (based on string length). E.g.:

```js
let output = ""
for(i=1; i<37; i++) {
  output += i.toString().padStart(2, " ")
  output += i % 10 === 0 ? "\n" : " "
}

document.querySelector("pre").append(output)
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Also, note that you can only have a single instance of an `id` in an HTML document. Rather than using `tracked` and `untracked` as `id` values, you can use them as `class` names:

```
<span class="untracked">…</span>

.untracked {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Note that if you require more than 1 space in a row, you'll need to apply `white-space: pre`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try to change the letter spacing for the first 10 numbers with letter-spacing: 3px;

Answer (score 0):

Another nowadays example via Flexbox.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.flex');
let maxNumber = 36;
let maxLength = 2;
let remain = maxNumber % 10;

for (i = 1; i <= maxNumber; i++) {
  let child = document.createElement("span");
  // → '9' to ' 9'
  let sequence = String(i).padStart(maxLength, '\xa0');
  child.textContent = sequence;

  if (i > (maxNumber - remain)) {
    // → 31 to 36
    child.classList.add("remaining");
  }
  container.appendChild(child);
}
```

```css
.flex {
  font: 14px Arial;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
  width: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0.3px solid #d4d4d4;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.flex>span {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.flex>.remaining {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

span:nth-child(11) {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

## i suggest padding the list of numbers less than ten with zeros

```
.less-than-ten:before{
```

content="0";
}